# WooCommerce переименовать кнопки

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как переименовать кнопку http://joxi.ru/4AkERPytM5dxbm в корзине.

Нашёл только этот код, подскажите куда дальше?

```
<div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) читаете [это](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/master/i18n/languages) 2) находите соответствующий файл с локализацией и меняете искомый текст (с ключом `msgid "Proceed to Checkout"`) на ваш. Только надо понимать как именно локализация проходит, поэтому советую перед этим почитать хотя бы [вот это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext)

Answer (score 1):

Выкачай сайт к себе на компьютер, открой все документы в Notepad. Нажми Ctrl+f и в поиске напиши "Перейти к оформлению". Нажимай на кнопку "Найти во всех открытых документах". Находишь эту фразу и меняешь в ручную. Потом файлы заливай назад на FTP, можешь только изменённые, а можешь и весь движок.

Answer (score 0):

Есть способ проще, total commander умеет искать по тексту внутри файлов. Просто подключаешься к серверу и запускаешь поиск по нужной фразе

Comment: вас не смутило то, что вопросу более 7 лет?

Comment: на что только не идут отчаянные пользователи ms/windows, чтобы не пользоваться программой grep...

Comment: был случай, когда меня этот вариант очень сильно выручил. Я искал сопоставления в двух проектах. Тотал коммандер очень внятно нашел разницу между ними. Так что если это выглядит глупо, но работает, значит - это не глупо